# Newtonsoft JSON, check if property and its value exists

Tags: c#, json, validation, json.net

I have an API where I get JSON as an input and I want to check if the specified property and it's value exists in that JSON.

**Note:** The JSON is not generated from code but is typed by the user so I cannot validate the JSON while serializing.

Consider the following JSON:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "someProperties": 
  {
    "property1": "abc",
    "property2": ["zzz", "ccc"]
  }
}
```

In `someProperties`, `property1` and `property2` both can either exists at the same time or anyone of them. So I want to check which all properties are present. And if present, whether that property has the valid value.

I tried the following code:

```
dynamic request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSONRequestData);
var X = request["someProperties"]["property1"];
```

Following are the two scenarios I have to check with their respective responses:

- If `"property1": "abc"` is **not** present in JSON then I am getting `null` in `X`
- If I put `property1` in JSON without its value which will look something like this `"property1": ,` then I am getting `null`.

So how do I differentiate between *property not being present* in JSON and *value of property not being present*?

Comment: if request["someProperties"] ！= null { // check request["someProperties"]["property1"] == null or not }

Comment: @urlreader No, if you request a property of a dynamic, and you get a `null` value, it can be because the property exists and has a value of null, or because the property doesn't exist. Just with this null value you can't distinguish between these two cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dynamic request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSONRequestData);` always creates a `request` as `JObject`, so you can use the methods of `JObject`. `JObject` itself implements the `IDictionary<string, JToken>` interface, which provides the `ContainsKey` method. So you can simply do

```
request.someproperties.ContainsKey("property1");
```

This will return `true` only if `someproperties` contains a property named `property1`, regardless of it's value. Ie, it doesn't matter if `request.someproperties.property1` is `null` or any type, as long as it is contained in the object.

See also [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gwXTm9)

Comment: Yes. This solution is working as required. Thank you @derpirscher

Answer (score 0):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var JobjectItem =
         System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonObject.Parse
                     ( [ json data ] ).AsObject();
    
    bool check = JobjectItem.ContainsKey([ key name ]);
```